# Call ODATA service with PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, odata, file-get-contents

I need to call ODATA services with php7.0 under Debian 9.

I'm trying to use "file_get_contents" function but when I run the script

```
$call_opts=array(
    "http"=>array(
        "method"=>"GET",
        "header"=>"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    )
);
//
$call_context=stream_context_create($call_opts);
$call_res_json=file_get_contents($url,false);
```

it return the following:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://<URL>): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

I have also user and password, but I don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "Authorization" in your header.
The HTTP Authorization request header contains the credentials to authenticate a user.

```
Authorization: Basic <credentials>
```

> If the "Basic" authentication scheme is used, the credentials are constructed like this:
>   - The username and the password are combined with a colon (aladdin:opensesame).
>   - The resulting string is base64 encoded (YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l).

Try with this code:

```
$username="auth_username";
$password="auth_password";

$call_opts=array(
    "http"=>array(
        "method"=>"GET",
        "header"=>"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password)."\r\n".
                  "Content-Type: application/json",
);
```